# How page specific should a viewmodel in MVC be?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I've understood that a viewmodel in MVC is supposed to reflect data on a single page rather than objects in the model. But **should the viewmodel correspond to the data you want to show on that page or to the data you want back from that page?** If we for example look at a login page then I just want **username** and **password** back in the post, but I might need more variables than that when displaying the login page (previous error messages etc).

Should the viewmodel then just contain **username** and **password** as parameters and the rest of the variables end up in viewbags. Or should the viewmodel contain all values I want to show even though I'm only interested in a few of them in the response.

What is best practice when using viewmodels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data that somehow interacts between the html and your server should be in a ViewModel.
This allows you to perform formatting and such outside your html and inside your ViewModel properties.

However, if your page contains a lot of controls or data, you may want to split it into multiple ViewModels (example one for the Get and one for the Post).
The post model may contain only data that you entered and needs to be validated.

Comment: How does it work to have different ViewModels for the Get and Post functions? Do I create a ViewModel specific for the Post reply (with only username and password), specify it as incoming parameter type and then expect MVC to fill it up based upon matching names among the incoming parameters, or how does it work?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. Just make sure that the names of your input fields correspond to the names of your Properties. then for you Post method in your controller, specify the Post Model as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to put everything in the view-model.  This keeps the code cleaner and makes discovery and maintenance easier as well.  The view-model should be your primary mechanism here.

Answer (score 1):

I would say only properties you need, in your case username and password. If you want to display error messages then that's what ModelState is for. You can always append any error messages to your ModelState:

```
 ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyName", "Error Text")
```

Beyond that let's say you have a form that contains a list of categories that you need to pick one category from a drop down. In this case I usually attach that list to my model even though the only thing being submitted is the actual selected value. But this is a matter of preference, meaning I could also set a ViewBag to contain this SelectList of categories and then bind that to your DropDownList. I suppose it's better to place this in a model because ViewBag is dynamic and you will have to cast anything in the ViewBag into it's underlying type on your views.

Comment: Yes, I'm not so keen on using ViewBags in general so I was hoping for some smart solutions showing up here :-)